# How to use JSON API to send messages from terminal to vim?

Tags: terminal, job-control

In `terminal.txt`, there is description about `terminal-api`, but it seems not to give a example to show how the message is send from terminal to vim function `Tapi_...`, is there some examples for the usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section [`:help terminal-api`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-api) includes a thorough description of the API and also an example function:

```
function Tapi_Impression(bufnum, arglist)
  if len(a:arglist) == 2
    echomsg "impression " . a:arglist[0]
    echomsg "count " . a:arglist[1]
  endif
endfunc
```

Then inside a `:term` you can call this function by sending a special sequence starting with `<Esc>]51;`, then including a JSON encoded list (whose first element is the string `"call"`, the second is the name of the function to call and the third a list of arguments to pass), finally followed by a `<07>`, which is the ASCII character with code 07, which is the "bell" control character.

In a shell (such as `bash`), you can use `echo -e` to have it interpret special sequences, and then `\e` to issue an `<Esc>` character, and `\a` for a "bell" which has ASCII code `<07>`. Putting it all together:

```
$ echo -ne '\e]51;["call", "Tapi_Impression", ["play", 14]]\a'
```

This will call the `Tapi_Impression` function, which in turn will print the following message (also available in `:messages`):

```
impression play
count 14
```